# What's the meaning of "pence" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a comment from a discussion on The effects of exercise on depression:

> For severe depression, this actually is pretty much the treatment routine. Pills to get just the tiniest amount of motivation, cognitive behavioral therapy to **pence** that motivation towards positive activities like regular exercise instead of suicide.
>
> Sounds severe, but that's how problematic deep depressions often are.

What does *pence* mean mentioned above? I've looked it up, but I couldn't find an entry in the dictionaries that defines *pence* in verb form.

Comment: It's never anything I've heard or read before, but my guess, after loading the contextual debugger, is that the speaker uses a transitive verb _to pence_ as short for something like 'to move in penny-packets'. _In/By penny-packets_ is not a phrase I use -- I'm American -- but I've run across it in print. It means roughly what Americans would say as 'in bits and pieces; gradually'.

Comment: I would say it's likely to be a typo. "Pence" does not seem to be used as a verb, since Google searching for "pencing" and "penced" don't yield any reasonable results. I can't figure out what it's a typo for, though.

Comment: @Peter Shor  My wife, who is a retired psychotherapist, does not recognise the term, reinforcing your theory of a typo. Do you suppose it could be something to do with 'penchant', meaning a tendency? That would seem to sort of fit with the context. Penchant comes from the French verb 'pencher', to lean or incline.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a (meaningless, incorrect) "one-off" usage. Perhaps an error for ***dispense*** (direct, distribute, apportion).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's an idea, yes, it could be 'dispense' I suppose. It wouldn't be the word I would have chosen, but possible.

Comment: @WS2: I don't personally find it all that convincing, but I can't think of any other credible "near misses". The rest of the text gives every impression of being from a native speaker, otherwise I'd have said a far more convincing explanation would be that the writer has accidentally used his own native (French) word [pencher](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/pencher) (to tip, tilt, incline [to favour]), as you suggested with the reference to [English] *penchant*.

Comment: There are typos on english.stackexchange and there are typos on reddit, where [this particular quote comes from](http://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/1pgl52/moderate_exercise_not_only_treats_but_prevents/cd2g184)

Comment: The only references to that text on the Web are to this forum and to a comment way down in a Canadian message forum.  "Pence" shows up only in that comment, so I agree with the others that this is either a typo, or somebody trying to coin a new word.    "Pence" is the plural of "penny".

Comment: The intended meaning is clear from context (I'd say _channel_ or _direct_) but I too cannot make any sense of the word, or think of anything it might be a typo for.

Comment: Since at this point we're reduced to speculating about what word the probable typo was supposed to be, I nominate _pince_, meaning (presumably) to pinch, pressure, or push.

Comment: https://twitter.com/RealSadBoy/status/153791027508019200 "Auto correct is ducking cap . A real pence of lieu."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a word which doesn't exists, or it is an inexplicable typo, or grammar/spelling mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I contacted the author of the quoted example and this is the response I got (emphasis mine):

> **In this context it's supposed to be analogous to "guide" or "direct".** The point of my argument being that antidepressants increase motivation for severely depressed. Unfortunately that motivation can be turned into negative activity, like attempting suicide or other forms of self harm, behaviors that earlier on was not enacted because the depression was so severe that there wasn't even enough motivation to go through with the suicide/self-harm, even if the self-loathing etc was even lower than it became after medication.
>
> It's known in psychiatry that medicating severely depressed people, can cause an increase in suicide attempts. This is well documented. **This is because there is now a little motivation, where earlier it was literally zero. That's why I said the motivation had to be "penced" towards healthy cognition and behavior.**

They then followed up with a second message explaining where "pence" originated:

> In my language "å pense" means to change the "switch" on a railroad track, so that when the train hits that fork, it will move to the left instead of right or vice versa.
>
> So it was not a typo, but a mistranslation from a Germanic language, specifically Norwegian.

Comment: Good research! Never would have guessed that Norwegian was the culprit. Learnt a new word in Norwegian, too. Kult. :-)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is a spell-checker correction for the neologism *incent* (first use 1981).

Answer (score 0):

Pence derives etymologically from the Latin for thought (pensee in French).  In this case, a pseudo-noun (compare recompense), perhaps misspelled, is being used to imply that a tiny bit of "thought power" is applied to mean moving a depression patient toward a desired goal.